# calling data frames in a for loop by a vector

Tags: r

I have some `data.frames`

```
dat1=read.table...
dat2=read.table...
dat3=read.table...
```

And I would to count the rows for each data set. So
the names are saved like this (cannot "change" it) vector=c("dat1","dat2","dat3...)

```
p <- vector(numeric, length=1:length(dat))
counting <- function(x) {for (i in 1:x){
      p[i]<-nrow(dat[i])}
return(p)
}
```

This is not working because the input for `nrow` is a character, but i need integer(?) or?

Thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get` for this, but be careful!  Instead reading the tables at a `list` is the R-ish way:

```
file.names <- list.files()

dat <- lapply(file.names, read.table)
```

Then you have all the conveniences of `lapply` and the `apply` family at your disposal, e.g.:

```
lapply(dat, nrow)
```

The solution using `get` (also `vector` is a bad variable name since its a very important function):

```
lapply(vector, function(x) nrow(get(x)))
```

Your method fails since there is no object called `dat` to index into.  The `for loop` could look like:

```
p = NULL
for(v in vector) {
  p <- c(p, nrow(get(v)))
}
```

But that technique is poor form for lotsa reasons...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine properties of items you know to be in the `.GlobalEnv`, this works:

```
> sapply( c("A","B"), function(objname) nrow(.GlobalEnv[[objname]])  )
A B 
5 4
```

You could substitute any character vector for  c("A","B")`. If the object is not in the global environment it just returns NULL, so it's reasonably robust.